# Why does this output wrong (get/set methods)

Tags: java

Just going through get/set methods and I'm having trouble with my output. Instead of displaying the First/Last name of the object it is displaying null/null.

Could anyone offer any insight, i'm not familiar with get/set methods.

Code

```
public class Person {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;    

public Person (String a, String b){

a = firstName;
b = lastName;
}

public String getfirstName(){

     return firstName;
}

public void setfirstName(){

     this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getlastName(){

    return lastName;
}

public void setlastName(){

    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String toString() {

String s = "First name:" + firstName + "Last name:" + lastName;
return s;

}
}
```

This is my class just to create the object and run to toString method

```
public class PersonDriver {

public static void main(String[]args){

    Person p1 = new Person ("Thomas", "Brown");

    System.out.print(p1.toString());
 }
}
```

Comment: its a general convention in getter and setter method that the first letter after set/get should start with CAPITAL letter eg.setLastName/getLastName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the parameters to the instance variables and not the reverse. What you're doing currently is reassigning `a` and `b` which were passed to the constructor, whereas you need to assign the values of `a` and `b` to the `firstName` and `lastname` fields of the class.

```
public Person (String a, String b){
    firstName = a;
    lastName = b;
}
```

Comment: Oh, had them the wrong way around. Now I feel stupid. Thanks.

Comment: class variables are nothing but static variables.

Comment: @AjayThakur - You've instance variables(class variables) which are unique for each instance of the class and static variables which are common to all the instances of the class.

Comment: @R.J in a sense he is right according to [this definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_variable) at lest

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev - Just to clarify, I didn't mean that, I changed it to instance variable. And this definition clearly states that *A class variable is not an instance variable.*

Comment: @R.J I am not the downvoter and I do not support the downvote here I am just saying. I believe now the downvote should be undone

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev - I never said that you're the downvoter. I just wanted to say that I corrected the answer, so that its not confusin anymore. I've been experiencing this the whole day, where some anonymous person has been downvoting all my answers regardless of anything, without comments.

Comment: @R.J You can report this on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) if you believe this is revenge downvoting.

Comment: I would wait for a longer time, and probably let the background serial voting script detect this. If it doesn't pick it and the downvoting continues, I would report it on meta.

Answer (score 1):

You inverted the variables within your constructor

You need  Change below code

```
public Person (String a, String b){

   a = firstName;
   b = lastName;
}
```

to

```
public Person (String a, String b){

    firstName = a;
    lastName = b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Primarily setters has to be

```
public void setFirstName(String firstName){

     this.firstName = firstName;
}


public void setLastName(String lastName){

    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

Comment: please make the first letter of the set/get name as capital letter like setFirstName +1

Answer (score 0):

Your setters should take an argument - the value to be set. Your constructor should assing the values of the arguments to the class properties not the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

I think the constructor has to be like

```
public Person (String a, String b){
    firstName = a;
    lastName = b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap the variabels. You assign the value of the object the parameters.

```
public Person (String a, String b){

firstName= a;
lastName= b;
}
```

Also your set method are useless without parameters :

```
public void setlastName(String parameter){

this.lastName = parameter;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You sure your methods shouldn't be more in line with this?

```
public class Person {

  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;    

  public Person (String a, String b){

   firstName=a;
   lastName=b;
  }

  public String getfirstName(){

    return firstName;
  }

  public void setfirstName(String firstName){

    this.firstName = firstName;
  }

  public String getlastName(){

    return lastName;
  }

  public void setlastName(String lastName){

    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  public String toString() {

  String s = "First name:" + firstName + "Last name:" + lastName;
  return s;

  }
  }
```

You need to pass the setter methods the values you would want to set the variables to. Apart from that, like the others mentioned, you swapped the variable names in the constructor. :)